# WooCommerce Preview Email Template. Separate sending and preview function

Tags: woocommerce

i have this part of code:

```
// load the email classs
$wc_emails = new WC_Emails();
$emails = $wc_emails->get_emails();

// select the email we want & trigger it to send
$email = $emails[ $email_class ];

// send email
$email->trigger( $wc_email_test_order_id );

// preview email content for browser
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mail_content', $email->style_inline( $email->get_content_html() ) );
```

Everything in one function. It is working this way:

1. select email
2. send email
3. preview email

I need to separate sending and preview emails.

- if I remove echo content for broser. It sends email. This is ok.
- if I remove the triger / echo content for broser not work alone without the trigger. This is the issue.

I need to make it work without the trigger (without sending emails out)

Comment: This is just a real development… You can have a look to the source code of [Woo Preview Emails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-preview-emails/) plugin, this will give you an idea of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Put a condition for preview email and add filters to disable email sending before the trigger method.

```
// load the email classs
$wc_emails = new WC_Emails();
$emails = $wc_emails->get_emails();

// select the email we want & trigger it to send
$email = $emails[ $email_class ];

// Disable email if preview check enable. 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_' . $email->id , '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_' . $email->id , '__return_false' );

// send email
$email->trigger( $wc_email_test_order_id );

// preview email content for browser
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mail_content', $email->style_inline( $email->get_content_html() ) );
```

So, it should display preview email but don't send an email with the trigger method.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, a bit late, but anyways it works. Here you can find the resuld: https://github.com/ThemesEmail/woocommerce-email-testing
you are mentioned in the plugin ;-) + 50e

Comment: Thanks, @JosephP.